# Finding how many bits are on in a number

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I know how to find out how many bits are on in a given number (or how many elements are true in a boolean arra), using a mask and bitwise operators, going over all bits checking if they are on. Assuming the number is of arbitrary length, the algorithm runs in O(n)  time, where n is the number of bits in the number. Is there an asymptotically better algorithm? I don't think that's possible, **but how can I formally prove it?**

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: did you read the question? why should he post code?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, the question doesn't refer to code. His existing code works. It's asking if another solution exists.

Comment: Depends on what you mean, you need to read all data, so `O(n)` is minimum on sequential machine. However, if `n` is smaller than word size you can do thing in parallel. Using C instructions in `O(lg n)`. Many processors can do this in `O(1)` time.

Comment: @joerick If OP's current algorighm/code is posted, better algorithm can be discovered by examining it.

Comment: @zch, I don't think I am interested in tricks such as parallel computation. I also wanted to say, it's O(n) "because you HAVE to look at all the bits". But can it be formalized?

Comment: @Idan Suppose we have algorithm, that is faster than `O(n)`. It means that for some input it will run is less than `n` time. So it can't access all data (what it exactly means depends on computation model). We flip one bit, which was not accessed. Algorithm will give the same result, but this time it isn't correct (it's off by one). Contradiction.

Comment: @zch: you're wrong. see answer below.

Comment: consider bolding **how can I formally prove it?**

Comment: @zch, I am not sure about this proof. if an algorithm is faster than O(n), it doesn't mean there exists a bit such that when flipping it  the result won't change (the algorithm can just return the number for example). An algorithm which does less than n operation can still receive all information needed in some smart way

Comment: @Idan I agree with zch's proof that an algorithm must be at least O(n) in the number of bits. That is a standard formulation for proving a lower bound: Suppose there is an algorithm that runs in less than *X* time. There are inputs *Y* and *Z* that it will be unable to distinguish, meaning it gives the wrong answer for at least one of them. The algorithm must be incorrect. Therefore, any correct algorithm must take at least *X* time to run.

Comment: Why running in less than X time ensures existence of indistinguishable Y and Z?

Comment: @zch, the confusion there is because people don't remember the definition of order statistics.  O(n) = O(number of bits se.  Proof is sketched in a comment below. Hell, I'm going to make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the type of formality you're looking for is an "adversarial proof".

Suppose one has an algorithm A that runs faster than O(n). Then for sufficiently large n, A must not look at some bit i. We then claim that A must be incorrect. An "adversary" will give A two strings s1 and s2 that are identical except for opposite values of bit i. The algorithm A will return the same value for s1 and s2, so the adversary has "tricked" A into giving the wrong answer. So no correct algorithm A running in o(n) time exists.

Answer (score 24):

[Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) presents a number of methods, including this one:

> #### Counting bits set, Brian Kernighan's way
>
> ```
> unsigned int v; // count the number of bits set in v
> unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v
> for (c = 0; v; c++)
> {
>   v &= v - 1; // clear the least significant bit set
> }
> ```
>
> Brian Kernighan's method goes through as many iterations as there are
>   set bits. So if we have a 32-bit word with only the high bit set, then
>   it will only go once through the loop.

Examples of the algorithm in action:

#### 128 == 10000000<sub>2</sub>, 1 bit set

```
128 & 127 ==   0    10000000 & 01111111 == 00000000
```

#### 177 == 10110001<sub>2</sub>, 4 bits set

```
177 & 176 == 176    10110001 & 10110000 == 10110000
176 & 175 == 160    10110000 & 10101111 == 10100000
160 & 159 == 128    10100000 & 10011111 == 10000000
128 & 127 ==   0    10000000 & 01111111 == 00000000
```

#### 255 == 11111111<sub>2</sub>, 8 bits set

```
255 & 254 == 254    11111111 & 11111110 == 11111110
254 & 253 == 252    11111110 & 11111101 == 11111100
252 & 251 == 248    11111100 & 11111011 == 11111000
248 & 247 == 240    11111000 & 11110111 == 11110000
240 & 239 == 224    11110000 & 11101111 == 11100000
224 & 223 == 192    11100000 & 11011111 == 11000000
192 & 191 == 128    11000000 & 10111111 == 10000000
128 & 127 ==   0    10000000 & 01111111 == 00000000
```

---

As for the language agnostic question of algorithmic complexity, it is not possible to do better than O(*n*) where *n* is the number of bits. Any algorithm must examine all of the bits in a number.

What's tricky about this is when you aren't careful about the definition of *n* and let *n* be "the number of bit shifting/masking instructions" or some such. If *n* is the number of bits then even a simple bit mask (`&`) is already an O(*n*) operation.

So, can this be done in better than O(*n*) bit tests? No.
Can it be done in fewer than O(*n*) add/shift/mask operations? Yes.

Comment: Still O(n), so it's not asymptotically better.

Comment: @CharlieMartin It's O(number of 1 bits) which is less than or equal to O(number of bits).

Comment: @john Thanks, That's an awesome algorithm. Doesn't v&(v-1) clear the most significant bit? Also, it's still worst case o(n), so I'm mainly interested in proving you can't get any better than that.

Comment: About the first question, it does clear the least significant bit, my bad

Comment: But if I allow such bit operations, is there an asymptotically better algorithm than O(n), where n is the length of the number?

Comment: @John and since it's for a constant size word O(number of bits set) = O(number of bits). Recall the definition of big-O.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: Your premise is correct (it's still `O(n)`), but your conclusion is wrong (it's also `O(c)`, which is asymptotically better than `O(n)`).

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I'd argue that `&` and `-` are not `O(n)` operations for machine primitives, and `unsigned int` is usually a machine primitive. Also note that zero tests (`for (...; v; ...)`) are free on some processors after operations like `v = ... & ...`.

Comment: @Tinctorius what happens all bits are set?  Go check the definition of big-O notation.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: assuming that zero-test and clear-least-significant-bit take `O(1)` time, the time this algorithm takes depends only on the number of bits that are set. This algorithm takes `O(number of bits set)`, because it executes zero-test and clear-least-significant-bit for every bit set, and it executes zero-test once before that. That `O(number of bits set)` is a subset of `O(number of bits)` is irrelevant.

Comment: OH, all right, we'll resort to proof.  Observe that by definition O(f(n)) says for some k and sufficiently large n, f(n) <= k g(n). Observe similarly that word length is a constant, say w, and as you note, the actual number of bits set per word varies from 0 to w.  But big O is upper bound, so we have to consider the worst case, n words of all bits set.  If follows the run time is w*g(n) were g(n) is your algorithm. Thus it follows that n <= w*g(n), and by definition the function is O(n). QED.

Answer (score 7):

I always use this:

```
int
count_bits(uint32_t v)
{
        v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
        v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
        return ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xf0f0f0f) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

You have to know the size of your integers.

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel

Comment: If you could explain what this does, it might be worth an upvote.

Comment: @ColinD Sorry. Can't remember. I just know it works well enough to count matches after performing intersections of large bitmaps. And I remember that the 64 bit version didn't change performance, so I stayed with the 32 bits version because it didn't spill over 80 columns (yes, that old).

Comment: This solution is not scalable to `arbitrary length` bit strings. The solution cited works up to 32 bit strings. The source link has a method that goes up to 128 bits.

Comment: First line counts pairs of bits, the 'and' is used to ensure the subtract does not overflow between pairs. After this line each two bit pair is the count of the bits in the original pair. The rest is summing up - first pairs to nibbles, then nibbles to bytes, and then the multiply sums the bytes such that the top byte is the total (other bytes are sub-totals). As you add one operation every time the number of bits doubles, this should be O(log n).

Comment: @JasonD Thanks, but Colin D is right, it doesn't work for arbitrary length. Can those constants be made to match any length?

Comment: Only if your desired length is something that can be processed in parallel on your target platform. So not arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

Brian Kerninghan's algorithm to count 1-bits.

```
unsigned int v; // count the number of bits set in v
unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v
for (c = 0; v; c++)
{
  v &= v - 1; // clear the least significant bit set
}
```

Read this and other bit-twiddling hacks here: [Bit-twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to do this calculation is with a table array edx[bl] where the bl register contains a byte value. If the number is a single byte then the answer is one instruction:

```
 mov eax, [edx:bl]
```

If the number has many bytes in it (say an array pointed to by ebp), then you loop through the bytes (where ecx is the number of bytes in the array containing the number):

```
    sub ecx, 1
    mov eax, 0
 DoNextByte:
    mov bl, [ebp:ecx]
    add eax, [edx:bl]
    test ecx, ecx
    jz Done:
    sub ecx, 1
    jmp DoNextByte:
 Done:
    ; answer is in eax
```

This is the absolute fastest way to do this and will be faster than any mathematical computation. Note that the shift instructions in Art's solution are very CPU expensive.

The problem with Kernighan's solution is that even when hand-coded in assembly it is slower than my algorithm. If it is compiled C it will probably generate a lot of memory accesses that will slow it down even beyond the larger number of clock cycles it requires.

Note that if the byte-to-count mapping is inlined right next to this instruction then the whole data table will be in the CPU cache so it will be really fast. In this case, no C program will even come close (think 20x slower or more).

Comment: Assuming you know what the CPU will put into cache with 100% certainty is a very large mistake. Also, I don't see this as being any different from @ap's answer

Comment: The Kernighan algorithm will loop an average of 4 times for every byte in the number. That means you will have an increment, a compare and an AND op x 4 for every byte, not including memory accesses. So it is guaranteed to be slower than a table lookup. If the table is inlined the chance that it is in the L1 cache is 99.99% in which case the table version will be mucho grande faster than the kernighan.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. Though I don't need a fast algorithm for anything in particular, I'm mainly interested in proving there doesn't exist an asymptotically better algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can also use a lookup table holding the #bits for each byte and then divide the number into bytes, adding up the lookup values.

It will be still O(number of bits) but with a small factor.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there seems to be some confusion here about order statistics, asymptotic notation, "big O".

It is correct that Brian Kernighan's algorithm is better in terms of number of operations.  It is, however, **not correct** that it is *asymptotically* better.

This can be seen from the [definition of big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Recall that by definition a function is *O(f(n))* when there exists a function *g(n)* such that *f(n) ≤ k g(n)* when *n* grows sufficiently large.

Now, let's define *w* to be the number of bits set in the word, and further note that the run time for a single word, as has been observed above, is a function of the number of bits set. Call that function *c(w)*.  We know that there's a fixed word width, call it *ww*; clearly for any word, 0 ≤ *c(w)* ≤ *ww*, and of course, worst case is that *c(w)* = *c(ww)*.  So, the run time of this algorithm is, at worst, *n c(ww)*.

Thus, for *n*, the run time is ≤ *n c(ww)*; that is, *n* ≤ *n c(ww)*, and thus by definition, this algorithm has an asymptotic worst-case run time of O(n).